# Entropy and Irreversibility

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, reversibility

I was watching *Tenet* and it made me think about some old questions I have. The second law of thermodynamics states that in every thermodynamics process, the variation of the entropy of a closed system is $\Delta S \ge 0$. If $\Delta S = 0$, the process is *reversible* and it is irreversible otherwise.

I understand the applicability of this result to isolated thermodynamic systems, such as those studied in thermodynamics courses. However, this seems to be the reason why our world does not go backwards, i.e. why there is an arrow of time. In physics books, one usually finds statements such as "if you jump into a pool, you cannot undo it" or "if you fry and egg you can't unfry it" and entropy seems to be the cause of these facts.

My question is: where is the thermodynamics of such claims? In other words, *how jumping into a pool or frying an egg can be seen as a thermodynamic process?* Maybe a more precise question should be: is the second law of thermodynamics the real reason why time goes in one direction and, in the end, everything is reduced to irreversible thermodynamic proccesses or is there another kind of entropy (maybe more fundamental) which explains these problems without reducing all these to thermodynamics?

Comment: How can they not? They are both thermodynamic processes.

Comment: To expand on the comment of @Yejus, I ask you OP to answer this leading question:  Can you at least identify the initial and final thermodynamic states for these processes?  If you are taking a course in thermodynamics, this should be pretty easy for you.

Comment: The fact that there is some thermodynamics involved is pretty clear to me. For instance, there is friction and, thus, heat flowing. If one jumps into a pool, the potential energy becomes sound and heat. But the point is that I these seems to be minor consequences of the changing system. When I think of someone jumping into a pool, for instance, I think of it much more as a mechanical system than of a thermodynamics system. Are these minor thermodynamics effects the real causes for nonreversibility?

Comment: The potential energy decreases, and the internal energy of the system (the person, the pool water, and the rest of the universe) increases by exactly the same amount.  The change in entropy for this process is positive.